# BenchmarkDotNet - Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create Benchmark one method but i got error `System.InvalidOperationException: „Sequence contains no matching element”`.

For example, I have limited my code to a very simple example:

```
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmark>();
 }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Benchmark
{
 private List<int> t = new List<int>(){5};

 [Benchmark]
 public List<int> AddElementsToList()
 {
  t.Add(1);
  return t;
 }
}
```

If i Run program in Release mod, Benchmark was run, but i got exception `System.InvalidOperationException: „Sequence contains no matching element”` and in console

```
OutOfMemoryException!
BenchmarkDotNet continues to run additional iterations until desired accuracy level 
is achieved. It's possible only if the benchmark method doesn't have any side-effects. 
If your benchmark allocates memory and keeps it alive, you are creating a memory leak.

You should redesign your benchmark and remove the side-effects. 
You can use 'OperationsPerInvoke', 'IterationSetup' and 'IterationCleanup' to do that.
```

Comment: I can run your code without any errors, and I get a result 
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1466 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i9-9880H CPU 2.30GHz, 1 CPU, 16 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.100-rc.1.21458.32
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.9 (5.0.921.35908), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.9 (5.0.921.35908), X64 RyuJIT

Run time: 00:00:34 (34.69 sec), executed benchmarks: 1

Global total time: 00:00:41 (41.33 sec), executed benchmarks: 1

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I find sollution in github documentation, That my computer does not have enough RAM to perform all iterations of the benchmark. It was enough that I changed its settings.

Comment: I get a outofmemoryException after sometime.  BenchmarkDotNet continues to run additional iterations until desired accuracy level is achieved. It's possible only if the benchmark method doesn't have any side-effects. If your benchmark allocates memory and keeps it alive, you are creating a memory leak.

@Ada You should redesign your benchmark and remove the side-effects. You can use OperationsPerInvoke, IterationSetup and IterationCleanup to do that.https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/faq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. My computer does not have enough RAM to run the given number of benchmark iterations. It was enough to change the benchmark settings to:

```
[SimpleJob(RunStrategy.ColdStart, launchCount: 1, warmupCount: 5, targetCount: 5, id: "FastAndDirtyJob")]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Benchmark
{
    private List<int> t = new List<int>() { 5 };

    [Benchmark]
    public List<int> AddElementsToList()
    {
        t.Add(1);
        return t;
    }
}
```